# Jenkins Build periodically with parameters doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, parameterized

I'm using Jenkins 2.46.2 version. I have installed  Parameterized Scheduler plugin to trigger the build periodically with different parameter.

[image]
But it fails to trigger the build at scheduled time.

Comment: has the job run at least once (can you trigger it manually)? i've seen an issue like this where it doesn't add the schedule until it runs the first time, but i haven't used this specific plugin.

Comment: job runs many times by passing the parameter manually. Its not working when using schedule with parameter

Comment: You are passing parameters to the scheduled job, but what is this $TAG. try with proper static value or remove this.

Answer (score 5):

You have a problem with the ";" on parameters. 
you have to insert space after each parameter, for example:
H/2 * * * * % EndMarket=can ;GitBranch=DevelopmantBranch

Comment: It seems a ninja technique. it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

try without spaces between params, like:

```
0 8  * * * % base_url=https://www.example.com;suite_type=Regression
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed the plugin on Jenkins 2.67, and it works. I had the same problem with builds failing to trigger with earlier version of Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, my parameter is Choice Parameter, so if I set the scheduler below and 'valueabc' is not in the list of choice, it will fail to start
H/15 * * * * %name=valueabc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).